# Recommendations for adding tooltips in D3.js barchart

Tags: d3.js, bar-chart, tooltip

I am extremely new to D3 and am attempting to make a simple bar graph with interaction. The data used for this is a short csv that contains book titles, average rating, and number of reviews. So far, I have successfully created that graph with a mouseover highlight feature. However, what I would really like is to have a tooltip appear when you hover over each bar that displays the average rating and the number of reviews.

The code I have so far is shown below. I've attempted a few different ways of adding in the tooltip into the onMouseOver functon, but each time it completely eliminates the whole graph.

I have made edits in refrence to the "D3.js mouseover event not working in bar charts" question; however, now only the title appears.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <style>
         .bar {
            fill: green;
         }
        
         .highlight {
            fill: red;
         }
         
         .title {
            fill: black;
            font-weight: bold;
         }
      </style>
      <script src = "https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
      <title> Animated bar chart </title>
   </head>

   <body>
      <svg width = "1000" height = "500"></svg>
      <script>
         var svg = d3.select("svg"),
         margin = 225, width = svg.attr("width") - margin,
         height = svg.attr("height") - margin;
         
         svg.append("text")
            .attr("transform", "translate(100,0)")
            .attr("x", 200).attr("y", 50)
            .attr("font-size", "20px")
            .attr("class", "title")
            .text("Average Rating of Most Reviewed Books")
            
         var x = d3.scaleBand().range([0, width]).padding(0.4),
         y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);
            
         var g = svg.append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + 100 + "," + 100 + ")");


         d3.csv("toprating.csv", function(error, data) {
            if (error) {
               throw error;
            }
             
         var tooltip = d3.select("svg")
            .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
            .style("position", "absolute")
            .style("visibility", "hidden")
            .text("Average Rating: " + d.avg_rating);
  
            x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.title; }));
            y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.avg_rating; })]);
                            
            g.append("g")
               .attr("class", "axis")
               .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
               .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
               .selectAll("text")
               .style("text-anchor", "end")
               .attr("dx", "-.8em")
               .attr("dy", ".15em")
               .attr("transform", "rotate(-65)");
           

            g.append("g")
               .append("text")
               .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
               .attr("y", 6)
               .attr("dy", "-5.1em")
               .attr("text-anchor", "end")
               .attr("font-size", "18px")
               .attr("stroke", "black")
               .text("Average Rating");
                         
            g.append("g")
               .attr("transform", "translate(0, 0)")
               .call(d3.axisLeft(y))

            g.selectAll(".bar")
               .data(data)
               .enter()
               .append("rect")
               .attr("class", "bar")
               .on("mouseover", onMouseOver) 
               .on("mouseout", onMouseOut)   
               .on("mouseover", tip.show)
               .on("mouseout", tip.hide)
               .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.title); })
               .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.avg_rating); })
               .attr("width", x.bandwidth()).transition()
               .ease(d3.easeLinear).duration(200)
               .delay(function (d, i) {
                  return i * 25;
               })
                  
            .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.avg_rating); });
         });

         function onMouseOver(d, i) {
            d3.select(this)
            .attr('class', 'highlight');
               
            d3.select(this)
               .transition()     
               .duration(200)
               .attr('width', x.bandwidth())
               .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.avg_rating) ; })
               .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.avg_rating); });
              
            g.append("text")
               .attr('class', 'val')
               .attr('x', function() {
                  return x(d.title);
               })
               
            .attr('y', function() {
               return y(d.value) ;
            })
         }
          
         function onMouseOut(d, i) {
             
            d3.select(this)
               .attr('class', 'bar');
            
            d3.select(this)
               .transition()     
               .duration(200)
               .attr('width', x.bandwidth())
               .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.avg_rating); })
               .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.avg_rating); });
            
            d3.selectAll('.val')
               .remove()
         }
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [D3.js mouseover event not working in bar charts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33945546/d3-js-mouseover-event-not-working-in-bar-charts)

Comment: I have made edits in reference to that question, but I am still having issues getting the graph to show.